# How to Add Dynamic image link in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using Google Forms/Sheets for tracking short-term employee evaluations at work. They're graded on three axis (performance, attitude, attendance).  I download data on performance and attendance, and use this to pre-fill the form URL with that data for each employee.

I'd like to be able to include a picture of the employee in the form, but that's beyond my current ability/knowledge.

Simplified sample sheet (simulating the pre-filled data) is here: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WUnrWzZ9vZwc0n7qs0d5MwZjeuCJMhkQuLeeo5UCfB4/edit?usp=sharing

I have, in a shared drive (mapped to G:\ for all managers) copies of the associates' badge photos.

Is it possible to incorporate something in the pre-filled URL data
 that will point to the photo for each associate, or otherwise
 dynamically incorporate that into the form, so that when people click
 on the link for entry #1 (Larry), at the top of the form is
 G:\shared\photos\1.png, entry #2 shows .\2.png, etc.?